# Can I move an option at the end of the select list?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this select:

```
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
    <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option>
    <option value="Test 3">Test 3</option>
    <option value="Test 4">Test 4</option>
    <option value="Test 5">Test 5</option>
    <option value="Test 6">Test 6</option>
    <option value="Test 7">Test 7</option>
    <option value="Test 8">Test 8</option>  
</select>
```

and I'd like to move the second option (Test 2) at the end of this select list. Can I with jQuery?

Comment: Why don't you just swap out the values of 'test 8' with 'test 2'? Also, could you give a more detailed explanation of what you're trying to accomplish by swapping the options?

Comment: Yes, you could, but you could also do this with a text editor.

Comment: @Jefferson, why? does every **clear** question has to mention the motivation behind it?

Comment: @gdoron, I'd just like to be able to understand the problem at hand before offering a viable solution.

Comment: @Jefferson,  I offered a solution  without knowing why he needs it(or even if he really needs it), questions should be concise and to the point, he of course can ask what is the best way to... but he didn't, and most of times those questions are not constructive at all.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var $select = $('#mySelect');
$select.find('option:eq(1)').appendTo($select);
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F73G3/)

Placing the option in the fifth  place:

```
var $select = $('#mySelect');
var desiredIndex = 5;
$select.find('option').eq(desiredIndex).before($select.find('option:eq(1)'));
```

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/F73G3/2/)

Comment: good answer..can we place option at certain position i.e at 5th position like that..

Answer (score 1):

```
var sel = $('#mySelect');
sel.find('option:eq(1)').appendTo(sel);  // insert to last position
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BzP4G/)

```
sel.find('option:eq(1)').insertAfter('option:eq(5)');  // insert to a specified position
```

[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/BzP4G/1/)

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#select_id option[value=thevalue]").insertAfter($("#select_id option:last"));
```